# Problem on Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Which of the following is most correct for the complex numbers Z and W, marked with "x" in the picture of the complex numbers below? (the dashed circle represents the unit circle)

a) $Z = W + 3i$

b) $Z = W^2$

c) $W = Z^2$

d) $Z = \dfrac{1}{W}$

e) $Z = 2W$

Picture here: http://s21.postimg.org/6tt471nd3/problem_complex_numbers.jpg

I think (c). But, I am not sure. What is your opinion?

Comment: I assume this is homework, so it's probably useful to go over the following question for future homework and exams: can you plot (on a 2D graph) the relationship between $Z$ and $W$ for each of the five cases?

Comment: Yes, that is what I did, but I was not quite sure if I was right. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(c) is correct. The angle of OZ vector doubles in order to be angle of OW vector.

Answer (score 0):

A complex number is a combination of a real number and an imaginary number. The modulus is the absolute value of a complex number

Answer (score 0):

When you add a number to Z, that is the same as translating Z. So Z=W+3i says that Z is up three units from W. 
When we do any multiplication or division, we want to think in polar. We we square (W=Z^2 for example) the modulus of Z is squared and the angle is doubled (which is what's happening here). So if Z is outside the unit circle, W will be further from the unit circle. If Z is inside the unit circle, W will get closer to 0.
For $z=\frac{1}{W}$,  the modulus of Z will be the reciprocral of the modulus of W (it will go from outside the unit circle to inside, or vice versa) and we replace the angle of W with it's opposite (flip it over the $\mathbb{R}$).
$Z=2W$ will preserve the angle and double the distance to 0.